# Problematic comboBox Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I use VS2008 C# + Windows Forms. I can't understand why comboBox does not behave the way it should.
In Design mode, I added a comboBox to my form, and edit Items to add "A" and "B". Double-clicking brings me to SelectedIndexChanged event, which I edit to display the selected text with MessageBox.

```
private void comboBoxImageSet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(comboBoxImageSet.SelectedText);
}
```

When I run, and select "A" or "B" in the comboBox, the MessageBox appears, but nothing is written.
Why?

Thanks.

Comment: just for grins, try ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedText
instead of going after the control try the instance running the event.

Answer (score 3):

Here the differences between the selection properties of a [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=VS.80).aspx) control.

1. [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=VS.80).aspx);
2. [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=VS.80).aspx);
3. [SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=VS.80).aspx);
4. [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=VS.80).aspx).

The `SelectedIndex` property :

> Gets or sets the index specifying the currently selected item.

Simply indicates the index of the selected item in the selection list. (Information provided for your kind information only. =))

---

The `SelectedItem` property :

> Gets or sets currently selected item in the `ComboBox`.

The *SelectedItem* represents the element that is currently selected as per the `ListControl` of the `ComboBox`. ***That is why this is what you want to use, to answer your question.***

---

The `SelectedText` property :

> Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a `ComboBox`.

That is, when you edit the `TextBox` portion of the `ComboBox`, the text that might be selected when you enter for edit, or any other type of *text* selection. This indeed does include any selection made through the `ListControl` portion of the `ComboBox`. For instance, if your [`ComboBox.DropDownStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle(v=VS.80).aspx) property is set to [`ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle(v=VS.80).aspx), then you will never be able to select any text in the editable portion of the `ComboBox`. Despite, you're able to select another item within the its list. ***That is why it is not the right property to use to serve your purpose.***

---

The `SelectedValue` property :

> Gets or sets the value of the member property specified by the `ValueMember` property.

Only used when using DataBinding, in conjunction with the `DisplayMember` property. For instance, when you want to display the name of a customer, and select him by his database Id, then the `DisplayMember` should display the customer's name, and the `ValueMember` the Id. This way, when you select one customer, the `SelectedValue` changes and raises the `SelectedValueChanged` event inherited from the `ListControl`. (Information provided for your kind information only. =))

---

Answer (score 2):

The SelectedText property returns the text that is marked in the combobox, not the selected item. If the combobox is editable you can mark a part of the text and the SelectedText property will return the marked text. [Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx).

What you are interested in is the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property or the [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

ComboBox.SelectedText

> A string that represents the currently
>   selected text in the combo box. If
>   DropDownStyle  is set to **DropDownList**,
>   the return value is an empty string
>   ("").

Use SelectedItem instead of SelectedText

Answer (score 0):

[SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets the text that is selected
>   in the editable portion of a ComboBox.

That is, it gets the text that is currently marked.

You want to use `SelectedItem.ToString()`.